# How many isomorphic subspaces does a 4- dimension vector space have?

Tags: linear-algebra

I think it should be five, from 0 to 4 dimensions, but not sure.

Comment: How many linear independent vectors are there? What does this mean for **one-dimensional** subspaces?

Comment: Sorry, I mean "How many isomorphic subspaces does a 4- dimension vector space have?" missed one word

Comment: Actually, I think you mean "up to isomorphism" rather than "isomorphic".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you've meant "how many subspaces up to isomorphism". Otherwise isomorphic to what?

In that case vector spaces are uniquely (up to isomorphism) determined by their dimension, i.e. two vector spaces $V, W$ over the same field are isomorphic if and only if they have the same dimension.

On the other hand if a dimension of a space $V$ is $n$, then for each number $i=0,\ldots,n$ there exists a subspace with dimension $i$. Indeed, you just take any basis $\{v_1,\ldots, v_n\}$ of $V$ and define $V_i=\mbox{span}(v_1,\ldots,v_i)$ and $V_0=\{0\}$.

Thus a vector space $V$ has exactly $\dim(V)+1$ subspaces up to isomorphism.

So yes, in your case it is $5$.